# Filter data in sheet 2 using date ranges selected in sheet 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a function that will give me the counts from other sheet. I have sheet 1 which has cell B1 and E1 where I select my criteria as dates then I have sheet2 where my data is. I want to get the counts of records in sheet 2 which match the date range selected in sheet 1 cell B1 and E1. here is the functions that I tried

None of these are working for me

```
=COUNTIFS(Scheduler!D3:D9,(Scheduler!C3:D9>=B1)*(Scheduler!C3:D9<=E1))
=COUNTIF(Scheduler!C3:D9,">=B1")-COUNTIF(Scheduler!C3:D9,"<=E1")
=COUNTIF(Scheduler!D3:D9,">="&B1)-COUNTIF(Scheduler!D3:D9,"<="&E1)
```

Comment: What is in `Scheduler!C3:C9` ?

Comment: Hi Scheduler is Sheet 2 name which contains Dates from cell C3 to C9

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Scheduler!C3:C9, ">=B1", Scheduler!C3:C9, "<=E1")` identifies how many of the dates in `Scheduler!C3:C9` fall between the dates `B1` and `E1`.  What is in `Scheduler!D3:D9`?

Comment: Scheduler!D3:D9 contains dates as well which at some point I will count them similar to the ones in C3:C9